# Can NASM generate a file with machine code hexdump + asm source?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

If I have the following Assembly code:

```
mov eax, 123
mov ebx, 321
```

Can NASM generate a file that shows the corresponding machine code for the Assembly code I showed, for example:

```
F2 FF A3    mov eax, 123
D7 D1 A1    mov ebx, 321
```

Comment: `nasm <source>` is the simplest command line that can do. You can specify an output filename if needed. `ndisasm -b <size> <binary>` will output the disassembly pretty much as you listed.

Comment: You asked for a NASM solution, and Cody and Margaret have provided that.  But there's also an [online solution](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) where you can just paste in the assembler to see the code bytes.  Useful for simple snippets.

Comment: Good suggestion, @David! I use that tool all the time. But the vast number of questions on SO about 16-bit assembly really make me wish it supported that mode, too. Or that there were fewer 16-bit asm questions on SO… Hmm

Comment: @CodyGray: Ugh, 16-bit.  After learning more than enough 16-bit crap from answering such questions, I eventually decided that it's not fun to answer them, and most of the time I don't even look at them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, NASM can absolutely do this. There are two basic approaches:

1. Have NASM generate a "listing" file as it assembles your code.

   To do this, pass [the `-l` option](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.3) on the command line when invoking NASM. If you like, you can specify an optional file name (it is conventional to use the `.lst` extension, but not required):

   ```
   nasm -f <format> SourceFile.asm -l ListingFile.lst
   ```

   A "listing" file displays the addresses and code bytes on the left, with the assembly mnemonics on the right. It also contains expansions of multi-line macros (except for those that have been defined with [the `.nolist` qualifier](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.3.11)).

   This does not inhibit assembly (the normal object file output is still generated), so you can just turn this option on in your Makefile and leave it.

   Here's an example of a listing file for a very simple source file:

   ```
   1 00000000 B87B000000              mov eax, 123
   2 00000005 BB41010000              mov ebx, 321
   3 0000000A CD80                    int 0x80
   4 0000000C C3                      ret
   ```

   The first column is the line number from the source code, the second column is the address/offset, and the third column is the binary value (for instructions, these are the machine code bytes; for data, this will be the raw binary data). The fourth, right-most column are the actual instruction mnemonics, as appear in your source code.

   Notice that the `MOV` instructions do not map to the machine code that is shown in the question… I don't know where you got those values. Maybe you just made them up?
2. Disassemble the object file or binary generated by NASM.

   Basically, you run the assembler to generate the output file, and then you run that back through a disassembler. NASM comes with a dissembler, called [NDISASM](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoca.html). The syntax is:

   ```
   ndisasm -b {16|32|64} filename
   ```

   where [the `-b` option](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoca.html#section-A.2) specifies the bitness of the file, which affects how the bytes are decoded into mnemonics. NDISASM defaults to 16-bit, but you will probably want 32-bit or 64-bit.

   There are some other options that you can read about in the above-linked documentation. These often come in handy, like specifying an origin for a COM file ([`-o`](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoca.html#section-A.2.1)), specifying a sync point to ignore data ([`-s`](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoca.html#section-A.2.2)), and skipping a header of a certain size ([`-e`](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/html/nasmdoca.html#section-A.2.4)).

   Here's an example of output from NDISASM:

   ```
   00000000  B87B000000        mov eax,0x7b
   00000005  BB41010000        mov ebx,0x141
   0000000A  CD80              int 0x80
   0000000C  C3                ret
   ```

   (No line numbers here, because the source code isn't used. It's just disassembling a binary, the same as you could do for *any* binary on your machine, whether or not you had the original source code.)

   Notice that NDISASM will print its output to stdout. You will likely want to redirect it to a file. How exactly you do that depends on which operating system you are using; consult your command interpreter's documentation for instructions.

Comment: *"Notice that the MOV instructions do not map to the machine code that is shown in the question… I don't know where you got those values. Maybe you just made them up?"* Yes I made them up :)